# SQL query that uses a GROUP BY and IN is too slow

Tags: sql

I am struggling to speed this SQL query up. I have tried removing all the fields besides the two SUM() functions and the Id field but it is still incredibly slow. It is currently taking 15 seconds to run. Does anyone have any suggestions to speed this up as it is currently causing a timeout on a page in my web app. I need the fields shown so I can't really remove them but there surely has to be a way to improve this?

```
SELECT [Customer].[iCustomerID],
                [Customer].[sCustomerSageCode],
                [Customer].[sCustomerName],
                [Customer].[sCustomerTelNo1],
                SUM([InvoiceItem].[fQtyOrdered]) AS [Quantity],
                SUM([InvoiceItem].[fNetAmount]) AS [Value]
FROM            [dbo].[Customer]
LEFT JOIN       [dbo].[CustomerAccountStatus] ON ([Customer].[iAccountStatusID] = [CustomerAccountStatus].[iAccountStatusID])
LEFT JOIN       [dbo].[SalesOrder] ON ([SalesOrder].[iCustomerID] = [dbo].[Customer].[iCustomerID])
LEFT JOIN       [Invoice] ON ([Invoice].[iCustomerID] = [Customer].[iCustomerID])
LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[InvoiceItem] ON ([Invoice].[iInvoiceNumber] = [InvoiceItem].[iInvoiceNumber])
WHERE           ([InvoiceItem].[sNominalCode] IN ('4000', '4001', '4002', '4004', '4005', '4006', '4007', '4010', '4015', '4016', '700000', '701001', '701002', '701003'))
AND(            ([dbo].[SalesOrder].[dOrderDateTime] >= '2013-01-01')
OR              ([dbo].[Customer].[dDateCreated] >= '2014-01-01'))
GROUP BY [Customer].[iCustomerID],[Customer].[sCustomerSageCode],[Customer].[sCustomerName], [Customer].[sCustomerTelNo1];
```

Comment: try put ([InvoiceItem].[sNominalCode] IN ('4000', '4001', ....) at last and check

Comment: It seems a simple query to me. On the other side, do you have any other queries, which take non reasonable amount of time to execute ? If so, it is not the query cause the trouble rather server clean cache.

Comment: Have you tried to do an 'EXPLAIN' on it, so the DBMS can tell you what it is doing?  You haven't said how many items are in your tables and which columns, if any, are indexed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this query is doing what you want anyway.  As written, there are no relationships between the `Invoice` table and the `SalesOrder` table.  This leads me to believe that it is producing a cartesian product between invoices and orders, so customers with lots of orders would be generating lots of unnecessary intermediate rows.

You can test this by removing the `SalesOrder` table from the query:

```
SELECT c.[iCustomerID], c.[sCustomerSageCode], c.[sCustomerName], c.[sCustomerTelNo1],
       SUM(it.[fQtyOrdered]) AS [Quantity], SUM(it.[fNetAmount]) AS [Value]
FROM [dbo].[Customer] c LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[CustomerAccountStatus] cas
     ON c.[iAccountStatusID] = cas.[iAccountStatusID] LEFT JOIN
     [Invoice] i
     ON (i.[iCustomerID] = c.[iCustomerID]) LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[InvoiceItem] it
     ON (i.[iInvoiceNumber] = it.[iInvoiceNumber])
WHERE it.[sNominalCode] IN ('4000', '4001', '4002', '4004', '4005', '4006', '4007', '4010', '4015', '4016', '700000', '701001', '701002', '701003') AND
      c.[dDateCreated] >= '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY c.[iCustomerID], c.[sCustomerSageCode], c.[sCustomerName], c.[sCustomerTelNo1];
```

If this works and you need the `SalesOrder`, then you will need to either pre-aggregate by `SalesOrder` or find better join keys.

The above query could benefit from an index on `Customer(dDateCreated, CustomerId)`.

Comment: I tried your query however it returns no rows. For the period specified this should not be the case. It did make me think about the query however and I used the date on the invoice item instead and scrapped the join on the sales order table which seems to have increased the speed greatly. I will also look at your suggestion on the index too. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of LEFT JOIN

I don't see CustomerAccountStatus usage. Ou can exclude it

The `[InvoiceItem].[sNominalCode]` could be null in case of LEFT JOIN so add [InvoiceItem].`[sNominalCode] is not null or <THE IN CONDITION>`

Also add the `is not null` checks to other conditions

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for customers that are either created this year or for which sales orders exist from last year or this year. So *select* from customers, but use *EXISTS* on SalesOrder. Then you want to count invoices. So outer join them and make sure to have the criteria in the ON clause. (sNominalCode will be NULL for any outer joined records. Hence asking for certain sNominalCode in the WHERE clause will turn your outer join into an inner join.)

```
SELECT 
  c.iCustomerID,
  c.sCustomerSageCode,
  c.sCustomerName,
  c.sCustomerTelNo1,
  SUM(ii.fQtyOrdered) AS Quantity,
  SUM(ii.fNetAmount) AS Value
FROM dbo.Customer c
LEFT JOIN dbo.Invoice  i ON (i.iCustomerID = c.iCustomerID)
LEFT JOIN dbo.InvoiceItem ii ON (ii.iInvoiceNumber = i.iInvoiceNumber AND ii.sNominalCode IN ('4000', '4001', '4002', '4004', '4005', '4006', '4007', '4010', '4015', '4016', '700000', '701001', '701002', '701003'))
WHERE c.dDateCreated >= '2014-01-01'
OR EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM dbo.SalesOrder
  WHERE iCustomerID = c.iCustomerID
  AND dOrderDateTime >= '2013-01-01'
  )
GROUP BY c.iCustomerID, c.sCustomerSageCode, c.sCustomerName, c.sCustomerTelNo1;
```